# Group Policy Screensaver's

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp, group-policy, windows

Recently my company has decided that you must have the company wallpaper and screensaver.

I have created two GPO's to do this applying to users within the domain, the first GPO applies the wallpaper which works correctly.

The second GPO applys the screensaver to company.scr and enforces timeout ect...

But on machines that have this policy enforced if you right click and go to display properties the screensaver displays "None", after looking in the C:\Windows\System32 folder to check the SCR file is correct i have noticed that the files are no longer screensavers but have been associated with kiXstart instead.

I have tried applying a reg fix to re-associate the files which works, but the screensaver tab in Display properties still shows as "None".

Does anyone have any ideas how I could fix this?

This may need to be on the superuser board instead but i believe its to do with the group policy somehow although i have used the same setup in different companies and this has worked.

Comment: If you logon iteractively, and perform a Start...Run and enter the .SCR path/filename, does it launch?

Comment: Before using the reg fix no, after using the fix yes but it is still not displayed on the display properties.